# Angular.js material md-icon

Tags: angularjs

I downloaded icomoon font, and imported it. Then I'm trying to show it in html:

```
<md-icon md-font-icon="glyph icon-cross"></md-icon>
```

But it's outputing this

```
<md-icon md-font-icon="glyph icon-cross" alt="android " class="ng-scope">
  <object class="md-icon"></object>
</md-icon>
```

Huh? It's same on [official docs](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.icon) but on their demo page it's working properly. Where's problem?

P.s. if I type html like `<span class="glyph icon-cross"></span>` icon is showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be due to the fact that this demo is working on `angular-material-0.8.0-rc1-master.js` and you may be using their latest stable version which is at the moment of writing is 0.7.1